# Linux mint cinnamon, application volume mixer

Tags: linux-mint

For the past few days ongoingly I have tried to find a application volume mixer applet. I.e I have been looking for an applet that will allow me to change the volume of each active application individually.

I found suggestion issue from 2013 on github:
https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/issues/1874

It says it was resolved with this PR:
https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/pull/3858

However with the default sound applet I still do not see any sound volume controls:
[image: Current sound applet]

The only way I have found to change the sound for different applications is nested in the sound settings:

[image: Current only way to change sound for different applications]

Does anyone know if there is a way to change the sound for different applications quickly using an applet in linux mint cinnamon edition?

I would be looking for functionality similar to this gnome extension:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3499/application-volume-mixer/

Thankyou in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the audio icon, you should see an application menu. Should be able to select volume per application there.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help!